# Test to create a new user on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I`m using Rails 5.1.3 in api mode and using devise for authentication.
I would like to do the following:

1 - During the creation of a new user, create a company (another model) with the name being the user email and set this company as the user's company
2 - Write a test to validate this scenario

In order to achieve item #1, I create my own registrations controller and override the create method, that look like this:

```
def create
    super
    if @user.persisted?
      company = Company.new(name: @user.email, users: [@user])
      @company.save
    end
end
```

But I'm not able to achieve item #2. I'm stuck with several different problem, depending on what I do. So, I have some questions:

a) Should I write a controller spec? Looks like this and fails because get a 200 instead of 201. But even this way, I`m not sure devise is really creating the user:

```
describe "Create user" do
    it "Must create a company when creating user" do
      post :create, :params =>{user: {email: "f@x.com"}}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    end
end
```

b) Should I write a request spec? Looks like this and fails with the same reason: gets an 200 instead of 201.

```
it "Must create a company when creating user" do
  post "/users", :params => {:user => {:email => "x@y.com"}}
  expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
end
```

c) Should I execute some curls to understand what is going on?

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST http://localhost:3000/users -d'{"user":{"email": "f@x.com"}}'
```

Then I got this error:

```
{"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"#\u003cActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

And got this at my server's console:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-08 01:46:43 -0300
Processing by MyDevise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"f@x.com"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>
{"email"=>"fuck@x.com"}}}
(0.6ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'fuck@x.com' LIMIT 1
(0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)  
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):  
app/controllers/my_devise/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

So, what I'm missing? Is it a CSRF problem? Do I need to configure something in order to devise work with my curls? Should use request spec or controller spec?

I found some examples on how to log in users during tests, but haven't found nothing on how to test the creation of a user.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: You're getting 406 because you are requesting JSON response but have not defined it in the controller. Not sure about the HTTP 200 here. But you can try some other matchers to see if the user is being created, e.g. `expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted`

Comment: In this snippet look like it's a problem, but I have changed this in the controller during my attempts and didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I would suggest you to not to pollute controller. Instead, use a before call_back

I am assuming there will be a `has_many` association between `company` and `users`

Using following code you can simply achieve your goal without writing a single piece of code in controller

class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company

```
before_create :associate_company

private def associate_company
  build_company(email: email)
end
```

end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
  end

Now for testing, you have to just test your models,
You can simply use shoulda_matchers for testing a `before call_back`

Note* This way you are creating a new compnay for every User. Is this exactly what you want?

I hope this works.